# How to prove expression correct

Tags: proof-verification

> Prove that for any positive integer $n $: $(2n)!$ is divisible by $({n!}) ^2: $

If you know a solution to the problem, please help..

*Sorry, this problem was edited by another user who changed some values. I have now fixed the problem.*

Comment: I don't get your question.  $n!$ is *not* necessarily a perfect square, e.g. $4!=24$ in between $4^2$ and $5^2$.

Comment: I dont understand the question. So you want to say for example for n=2 that 4!=24 is divisible by sqrt(2)? LOL, 3 same comments

Comment: From the very original version of the question, I believe that you want to say $(n!)^2$ divides $(2n)!$---but this is simply the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$, which is an integer.

Comment: $n!$ is never a square for $n>1$, so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your original version was "2 in (n!)2 is actually a square root", so don't blame others, please.

Comment: $\binom{2n}{n} $ is the simple answer to this. otherwise , you need to use the formula of checking the exponent of a  prime $p$ in both $ 2n !$ and $n!$ using the De Polignac's Formula and show that the former is atleast two times more than the latter one.

Comment: To display square roots, use \sqrt.  If the argument is more than one character enclose it in braces.  So \sqrt {100} gives $\sqrt {100}$

Answer (score 1):

From the comments $\frac {(2n)}{(n!)^2}={2n \choose n}$, which is guaranteed to be an integer.